# Raise an Event Except when something happpen

Tags: c#, winforms, events

**Scenario:** Only If the user follow the path **Click on ListView > Click on Button** the Button1 do something.

In other word I want to check in *Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)* if the previous focus was on ListView.

So I tried this:

```
private void ListView_Test_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _focusedControl = null;
    }
```

I want raise previous event except when this event is raised:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if(_focusedControl == listView_Test)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**   I have a variable that holds a reference to the currently focused control:

```
private Control _focusedControl;
```

and I update it in this way:

```
    private void ListView_Test_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
        _focusedControl = (Control)sender;
    }
```

If the user follow the path **Click on ListView > Click on Button** I want raise only the Button1_Click event, in all other case I want normal raise.

Comment: Can you describe more in depth what you're trying to achieve or prevent from happening?

Comment: Maybe you just want to set the Focus back to the ListView?

Comment: @Jimi I edited my topic. Check it now.

Comment: So is the button outside of the listview? Are you trying to click a button by leaving the listview BUT not wanting the listview leave event to fire because you need a value in _focusedControl?

Comment: @mindsurfer_BS yes

Comment: @Jimi I need the variable `_focuseControl` because in the `Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` I want to check if the Focus WAS on ListView 
if it is so I want to do some operetion.

Comment: 1) (in a `Leave` event) `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _focusedControl = null));` and check `_focusedControl` in `[Button].MouseDown` (in this case, `MouseDown` is raised before the `Leave` event of the Control that *BeginInvokes* sets the Field). 2) Make the Button non-selectable (Custom Control with `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` in the Constructor), so it won't *steal* the Focus and the `Leave` event of other controls is not raised. 3) Change the design.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper variable.

```
bool wasRaised=false;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { wasRaised=true;}
```

Then you can check that variable in your event, and only run if it is false.

Comment: The Leave event is raised way before the Click event of another Control

Comment: @Jimi exact. I try this but doesn't work because the Leave event is raised before the Click event.

Comment: @Giovanni So you want to stop an event from being raised unless another event will be raised in the future?? I think you'll have to provide some more info if you want any useful answers.